# Fast rangesearch implementation in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I'm going to implement the same function as rangesearch in matlab. The problem is the data is really big(6.7million 3D points). I read [Pairwise Distance Calculation in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253405/pairwise-distance-calculation-in-c) and improve my code but it is not fast enough yet. Since computing distance matrix is Ram consuming for this amount of data it is not applicable. I put my code here. Let me know if there is a way to make it faster.I'm not sure does parallelization helps here or not. The data is sorted on 1st dimension and I want to make sure that for every point the first neighbour is the point itself.

```
std::vector<std::vector<long int>> rangesearch(std::vector<std::vector<float>> &data, float radius) {
    float distmat = 0;
    float xdist = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<long int>> indices(data.size());

    //This make sure that the first neighbour of each point is itself.
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        indices[i].push_back(i);
    }

    // instead of computing sqrt() of distance, compute the 2nd power of radius once and compare it again and again which is faster
    radius = std::pow(radius, 2);

    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (long int j = i + 1; j < data.size(); j++) {

            xdist = std::pow(data[i][0] - data[j][0], 2);
            distmat = xdist + std::pow(data[i][1] - data[j][1], 2) + std::pow(data[i][2] - data[j][2], 2);

            if (distmat <= radius) {
                indices[i].push_back(j);
                indices[j].push_back(i);
            }

            //This is just to make the preprocessing faster. Data should be sorted based on X cordinates.
            //Then if the distance for x cordinate is bigger than radius it means that it will be even bigger
            // for the rest of the point so there is no need to check all of them and skip the rest!
            if (xdist > radius)
                break;
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`... should it be `std::vector<Point3D>` or `std::vector<std::array<float, 3>>`. It would take less memory and indirection.

Comment: If you have 3D points, don't use a (dynamically sized) `std::vector` to represent the points.  (Your first loop does `data.size()` memory allocations, and your points are not necessarily located together.) Use a struct or a tuple or a `std::array`.

Comment: [Sweep_line_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) might help.

Comment: Why is `i` an `unsigned long int` while `j` is a (signed) `long int`?

Comment: This problem is to broad. Optimizations for particles interacting by gravity is quite complex problem. Sweep line algorithm is not very helpful here. For example split space into a buckets. For each bucket calculate center of mass and mass of particle in it. Now each particle interacts with particles in same and neighbor buckets and interaction with other particles are counted using mas and place of other buckets. This should speed up things a lot without loosing to much of a precision (if parameters are properly provided). Strategy for selecting buckets is also complex problem.

Comment: profiling shows that big performance penalty is paid for push_back operations... Even commenting out the loop with indices[i].push_back(i) gives significant time saving. I'm wondering if working with memory mapped file or other external cache would help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you are trying to solve looks like a **nearest-neighbor search** or a *n-body simulation*.

The worst-case complexity of the current code is `O(n^2)`. With `n=6.7e6`, this means about ten thousand billion iterations. Sure, the breaking condition, parallelism and low-level optimizations will help a bit, but the resulting code will still be very slow. Thus, you need to *find a better algorithm*.

The common way to solve this kind of problem consists in putting all elements in a [BSP-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) data structure (such as [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). Such a data structure helps you to locate the nearest elements near a location in a `O(log(n))` time. As a result, the overall complexity of this method is `O(n log(n))`!

**Important note:** *I assumed the radius is small*. Indeed, if `radius` is too big, then you need to iterate over the whole tree resulting in a quadratic complexity. Actually, in this case the size of the written output is quadratic. Thus, `O(n^2)` would be unfortunately the optimal complexity.